# NumPy Array to Feature Writes only first array object to feature class

Tags: python, arcpy, numpy

I am consuming a json web-service with NumPy Array to Feature, I have many nested try/except blocks to consume the data/find errors/etc.  The script is functional, however I am having trouble seeing where I am obviously not accounting for a loop to consume the data.

Here is a crude example of my code structure; I am writing the first json object that I loop through to my db, although hundreds are returned.  How can I adjust my code to account for all of my loops and incoming data?

```
import json
import jsonpickle
import requests
import arcpy
import numpy as np
import time
import datetime
import logging
import logging.handlers
import smtplib


#overall exception handling
class TlsSMTPHandler(logging.handlers.SMTPHandler):
     def emit(self, record):
    try:
        import smtplib
        import string # for tls add this line


  except:
            do something

logger = logging.getLogger()


#arcpy e-mail handling
try:
    def sendResultEmail(msgContents, success_TF):


try:
        if arcpy.Exists(fc):
            arcpy.Delete_management(fc)
    try:
           requests stuff
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout as e:
            print "Too slow Mojo!"


    if last_run != now_minus_5:
            print "this block is activated"
    try:
        items = []
        for sr in decoded2['Response']['ListOfServiceRequest']['ServiceRequest']:
            SRAddress = sr['SRAddress']
            # SRType = sr['SRType']
            if sr['Latitude'] != '':
                y = sr['Latitude']
            if sr['Longitude'] != '':
                x = sr['Longitude']
            if sr['Latitude'] == '':
                blanky = sr['Latitude']
            if sr['Longitude'] == '':
                blankx= sr['Longitude']
                print blanky
                print blankx

            #many try except blocks that consume data
              try:
                locationEwastePrevious = ''
                for sr in ElectronicWaste:
                        for ewastelocation in ElectronicWaste['La311ElectronicWaste']:
                                            locationewaste = ewastelocation['CollectionLocation']
                                            if locationEwastePrevious != locationewaste:
                                                locationEwastePrevious = locationewaste


            except:
                print "No Electronic Waste Types"

            try:
                itemEwastePrevious = ''
                for sr in ElectronicWaste:
                        for ewastetype in ElectronicWaste['La311ElectronicWaste']:
                                        itemEwaste =  ewastetype['ElectronicWestType']
                                        if itemEwastePrevious != itemEwaste:
                                            itemEwastePrevious = itemEwaste
            except:
                print"No Ewaste items"


            try:
                iteminfoewasteprevious = ''
                countEwastePrevious = ''
                for sr in ElectronicWaste:
                        for ewastecount in ElectronicWaste['La311ElectronicWaste']:
                                        countEwaste = ewastecount['ItemCount']
                                        if countEwastePrevious != countEwaste:
                                            countEwastePrevious = countEwaste
                                            iteminfoewaste = '{0},  {1}, '.format(countEwastePrevious, itemEwastePrevious)
                                            if iteminfoewasteprevious != iteminfoewaste:
                                                iteminfoewasteprevious = iteminfoewaste

            ItemDesc = BulkyItemInfo + DACItemInfo
            outputobjects= int(decoded2['Response']['NumOutputObjects'])

            dt = np.dtype([('Address', 'U40'),
                        ('LatitudeShape', '<f8'),
                        ('LongitudeShape', '<f8'),
                        ('Latitude', '<f8'),
                        ('Longitude', '<f8'),
                        ('ReasonCode','U128'),
                        ('SRNumber', 'U40'),
                        ('FirstName', 'U40'),
                       ('LastName', 'U40'),
                        ('ResolutionCode','U128'),
                       ('HomePhone', 'U40'),
                        ('CreatedDate', 'U128'),
                        ('UpdatedDate', 'U128'),
                        ('ItemDesc','U128' ),

                        ])

            items.append((SRAddress,
                             x,

                            y,
                              x,
                              y,
                              ReasonCode,
                              SRNumber,
                             FirstName,
                              LastName,
                              ResolutionCode,
                              HomePhone,
                              CreatedDate,
                              UpdatedDate,
                              ItemDesc,

                            ))
            sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)

            arr = np.array(items,dtype=dt)
            NumPyArray = arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToFeatureClass(arr, fc, ['longitudeshape', 'latitudeshape'], sr)

    except:
        print "this does not work"
except arcpy.ExecuteError:
            strResult += arcpy.GetMessages()
            arcpy.AddMessage(strResult)
```

Output: I am expecting 187 different types for this request.  This output writes correctly to my FC.

```
[ (u'4437 1/2 W LOCKWOOD AVE, 90029', -118.290563, 34.08883, -118.290563, 34.08883, u'44', u'1-7868751', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'2015-03-23 14:35:39', u'2015-05-26 06:39:15', u' 1, Bird Cage (Plastic)  ')]
```

Comment: `items` appears to be getting appended to only once (it's not within any of your for loops as far as I can see). Could possibly be an indentation issue, as there is a confusing mix of indentation here.

Comment: The indentation is a bit confusing but entirely necessary, how would I assure that `items` is appeneded to for the count of my returned records?

Comment: I disagree. Any decent IDE will throw up multiple objections to the pattern of indentation in the code you listed above. My hunch is that `items.append` is supposed to be within a for loop, but it isn't right now.

Comment: I guess more to the point, if you standardized on 4 spaces per level of indentation, it would be easier to understand the flow of the code.

Comment: Please see the complete code example here; http://codepad.org/Dp1ZiViV

Comment: Are you expecting multiple records from `aTable`?

Comment: Yes, for every row that is record that is returned in my json response, there should be a corresponding row indicating it has been written to the db.

Answer (score 2):

A few things here, not all of them might be contributing to the problem, but all of them strike me as a possible issue.

`arcpy.da.SearchCursor` gets opened, but only one record is ever accessed (there is no `for` loop on cursor, or multiple `.next()` calls.)

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(aTable, return_flds, where_clause=where_str, sql_clause=sql_clause) as cursor:
    last_row = cursor.next()
```

Also for each `sr` from this line:

```
        for sr in decoded2['Response']['ListOfServiceRequest']['ServiceRequest']:
```

`items` gets updated and then written out with the `NumPyArrayToFeatureClass` line. I believe the way the logic is set up, you'll never get more one item in `items`.

This pattern of logic below also seems off (there are 3 consecutive cases). As `updateRow` is only called after the entire `fc` has been iterated over. Maybe `updateRow` should be within the for loop.

```
            cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
            for row in cursor:
                row.setValue(CreatedDate, row.getValue("CreatedDate"))
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

This too for a similar reason, as only one row will get inserted because all the `setValue` and `insertRow` calls come outside of the for loop.

```
            rows = arcpy.InsertCursor(aTable)

            for x in xrange(0, outputobjects):
                row = rows.newRow()
            row.setValue("Success", 'YES')
            row.setValue("Fail", 'NO')
            row.setValue("Time", Start)
            rows.insertRow(row)
```

Comment: All of the curosor functions are designed to query the last rows, so that is correct. However, I am not certain that your explanation is correct for `items`  While designing this I tested the consumption of data without all of the expection handling and it works, meaning that all features/JSON objects are written to my FC.  I haven't been able to see what the limiting factor is between the two scripts, the indentation does make a bit confusing.  Please see this script which functions correctly without the exception handlers. http://codepad.org/Gzb3px1R   line 500 specifically. excuse comments.